# Storing a Cookie

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, cookies

Ok Soo I have 3 Sites.  All need to store a cookie that each site needs to be able to see.
I have a Single ASPX that stores this cookie for all 3 sites..
Basically On each page on the site there is a javascript that calls the ASPX and makes it store the cookie.  If the ASPX is on one domain and im loading the aspx as an image, why does each site not write to the same cookie?  Basically let me break it down this way.

X.com
y.com
z.com 
all exist

y.com/cookiesave.aspx also exists.  It writes a coookie called bob and sets it to a Guid if it doesn't exist...

x.com, y.com, and z.com on all pages basically have a javascript that loads an image from y.com/cookiesave.aspx which returns a 1x1 transparent image.
Yet it doesn't seem to see these cookies coming from y.com.
It still sees all three sites as saving and loading the cookie seperately.  How the heck does it know if the script is on y.com only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protections that stop this are put in place by the browser makers to prevent cross site scripting attacks.  If you have a legitimate goal then implement it in this way; use `x.my.com`, `y.my.com` and `z.my.com` and set your cookie(s) for `my.com` and not for each one.

Also note:  The protections against this kind of action are not just stopped by the browser, there are also security gateways, firewalls, etc that look for this behavior because it is assumed to be an attack.  Unless you are performing an attack do it the way I suggest.  Oh, and don't perform an attack -- if that is what you are thinking of doing.

Comment: My goal is more of an analytics type of goal... I catch the IP Address but an ip address is only accurate to the firewall which it is behind.  I wanted to drop a guid on that machine so that I knew when that exact machine was coming back to the site but multiple domains could have the analytic script on it..  I will ponder not performing an attack :) haha definately not the goal.  Appreciate the thought

Comment: @Rico : Take a look at "evercookie".  I believe it might blow your mind >> http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: WOw Evercookie is pretty cool.... If it solved my problem that would be even better but it may solve other problems further down the line..

Comment: OMG, evercookie is just... evil.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies must have the same originating domain. For any cookie there are two key values *cookie domain* and *cookie path*. A cookie domain is default set to the domain of the page loaded. For instance `www.foo.com`. If you want to share a cookie between domains, these domains must be something like:

```
a.foo.com
b.foo.com
c.foo.com
```

In which case the *cookie domain* must be set to `foo.com` (you can't set `com`).

The cookie path is the path on the server that the cookie should be returned for. Most often you set this to `/` which means any path will get the cookie. But you can set it to `/something` and then any page like `/something/here/` will get the cookie.

**Edit:**

Most browsers block cookies from any 3rd party that are not the page you're visiting.

[image: Cookie blocking]

Comment: My goal is more of an analytics type of goal... I catch the IP Address but an ip address is only accurate to the firewall which it is behind. I wanted to drop a guid on that machine so that I knew when that exact machine was coming back to the site but multiple domains could have the analytic script on it

Comment: You'll find that many browsers these days only allow cookies from the domain of the page that was loaded in the browser. So even if you insert an image from one single domain on all three different sites, you won't be able to set a cookie.

Comment: your answer makes sense and i get the 3rd party settings.. Thought i could force it i guess.  Browsers aren't as dumb as i expect it seems :)
Live and learn...